# PHP not outputting CSV from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, csv

I have a button that when clicked is supposed to submit variables to an ajax call which then a csv is created and downloaded but for some reason the file just isnt downloading. Yet I get the correct output in Chrome Dev tools:

Here is what I have:

**index.php**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post">
<input hidden id="ajaxquery" value="<?php echo $ajaxquery;?>">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="downloadcsv">Download CSV</button>
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var csvquery = function(){
    function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}     
    ajaxquery = $('#ajaxquery').val();
    department = getUrlParameter('department');
    startdate = getUrlParameter('startdate');
    enddate = getUrlParameter('enddate');
    staffsearch = getUrlParameter('staffsearch');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST', // type
                    url: '../report/csv.php', // request file the 'check_email.php'
                    data: {ajaxquery:ajaxquery, department: department, startdate:startdate, enddate: enddate, staffsearch: staffsearch},
                    success: function(responseText) {

    }
                    }); // end success
            }
$('#downloadcsv').click(csvquery);
});
```

**csv.php**

```
session_start();
require '../connect.php';
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Department','Hours Worked', 'On Holiday', 'Ill' , 'Date'));

$sql = "SELECT time.id as timeid, time.staff_id, time.timein, time.onholiday, time.dateadded, time.ill, time.notes, staff.id AS staffid, department.id AS departmentid, department.department_name, staff.staff_name, staff.department_id FROM time, staff, department WHERE staff.id = time.staff_id AND staff.department_id = department.id ORDER BY `time`.`dateadded` ASC ;";

$rows = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
while ($rowcsv = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)){ 
    fputcsv($output, array($rowcsv['staff_name'],$rowcsv['department_name'],$rowcsv['timein'],$rowcsv['onholiday'],$rowcsv['ill'],$rowcsv['dateadded']));
};
readfile("php://output");
```

Comment: Have you checked any console logs for any data coming back from the ajax call?

Comment: Yes I get the output coming back in Dev Tools response window when I click on csv.php. (@danny-broadbent you have the same name as my brother :D)

Comment: Name,Department,"Hours Worked","On Holiday",Ill,Date
staff3,Accounts,7,yes,,2015-06-16
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,7,yes,yes,2015-06-17
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,7,yes,yes,2015-06-18
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,4,yes,,2015-06-19
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,6,,,2015-06-20
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,6,yes,,2015-06-21
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,8,,yes,2015-06-23
"John Smith","Marketing and Pricing",7,yes,,2015-06-23
name,Audit,3,,,2015-06-23
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,7,,,2015-06-24
"Joe Bloggs",Audit,7,,,2015-06-29
"John Smith","Marketing and Pricing",8,,,2015-06-29
staff3,Accounts,9,,,2015-06-29
name,Audit,9.6,,,2015-06-29

Comment: Rather than using $.aJax i would suggest you use $.fileDownload();

Comment: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js

Comment: lol @ at the name, a cousin of my is called Anthony :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change aJax to fileDownload:

```
$.fileDownload('../report/csv.php', {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    data: {
        ajaxquery:ajaxquery, department: department, startdate:startdate, enddate: enddate, staffsearch: staffsearch
    },
    successCallback: function (url) {
        //insert success code

    },
    failCallback: function (html, url) {
        //insert fail code
    }
});
```

You can use jQuery fileDownload method through this js file:
https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js

More information at:
http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: Wow that works perfectly. I didnt want to use plugins as CSV downloads are fairly simple but not this one. I owe you a pint :D. I dont have enough rep to upvote :(

Comment: Lol no problem, glad it helped! :) im out of votes today, so can't up your post until tomorrow